# Redpark Serial Cable Modbus RTU iOS

Tags: ios, modbus, external-accessory

I'm playing around with a [Redpark Serial Cable](http://redpark.com/lightning-serial-cable-l2-db9v/) and the External Accessory Framework to be able to talk to a device through ModBus RTU using [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org/). I found an [objective-c wrapper](https://github.com/iUtvikler/ObjectiveLibModbus) that I have already used to do this through ModBus TCP.

I am having trouble getting the library to use the Serial Cable as the device to connect. I was wondering if anyone has tried doing this before.

My question really is how does iOS "talk" to the external accessory? What are the paths to these port locations?

I believe in OSX these paths lie in the /dev directory

I am trying to use the following function

```
modbus_t *modbus_new_rtu(const char *device, int baud, char parity, int data_bit, int stop_bit);
```

Here is the [documentation](http://libmodbus.org/docs/v3.0.6/modbus_new_rtu.html).

Answer (score 0):

From my brief research on the Redpark Lightning Serial Cable, the cable works with the Rsc Mgr SDK. I suspect you'll need to port libmodbus to iOS using the Rsc Mgr SDK for access to the serial data rather than having libmodbus open a serial port directly.

> When the iOS accessory manager receives data from the cable and we
>   receive an event that data is available in the read stream, the
>   readBytesAvailable call is made - [source](http://redpark.com/developers/)

iOS appears to talk to the external accessory via the iOS accessory manager.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late for an answer but I'll give it a go anyway. You will have to modify the Modbus RTU implementation in the original libmodbus using the redpark sdk interface read/write methods. And adapting the serial settings to the redpark sdk. A decent guideline may be to look at the Arduino implementation for libmodbus. It has modifications to run on Arduino. And since the Redpark SDK is objective C, the libmodbus files will need to be changed to a '.m' extension.